# Scrapy can't figure out an sql query ins ajax call

Tags: sql, ajax, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from this link https://www.flatstats.co.uk/racing-system-builder.php using scrapy.

I want to automate the ajax call using scrapy. 
When I click "Full SP" Button (inspect in Firebug) the post parameter has the sql string which is "strange" 
`race|2|eq|Ordinary|0|~tRIDER_TYPE`
What dialect is this?

My code :

```
import scrapy
import urllib

class FlatStat(scrapy.Spider):

    name= "flatstat"
    allowed_domains = ["flatstats.co.uk"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.flatstats.co.uk/racing-system-builder.php"]

    def parse(self, response):

        query_lst = response.xpath('//table[@id="system"]//tr/td[last()]/text()').extract()
        query_str = ' '.join(query_lst)

        url = 'https://www.flatstats.co.uk/ajax/sb_report.php'

        body_dict = {'a_e_max': '9.99',
                     'a_e_min': '0',
                     'arch_min': '0',
                     'exp_min': '0',
                     'report_type':'S',
                     # copied from the Post parameters by inspecting. Actually I tried everything.
                     'sqlFullString' : u'''Type%20(Rider)%7C%3D%7COrdinary%20(Exclude%20Amatr%2C%20App%2C%20Lady%20Races
                                         )%7CAND%7Crace%7C2%7C0%7COrdinary%7C0%7C~tRIDER_TYPE%7C-t%7Ceq''',
                     #I tried copying this from the post parameters as well but no success.
                     #I also tried sql from the table //td text() which is "normal" sql but no success
                     'sqlString': query_str}

        #here i tried everything FormRequest as well though there is no form.
        return scrapy.Request(url, method="POST", body=urllib.urlencode(body_dict), callback=self.parse_page)


    def parse_page(self, response):

        with open("response.html", "w") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

So questions are:

1. What is this sql.

   2. Why isn't it returning me the required page. How can I run the right query?
   3. I tried Selenium as well to click the button and let it do the stuff it self but that is another unsuccessful story. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to say what the website creator is doing with the submitted `sqlString`. It probably means something very specific to how the data is processed by their backend.

This is an extract of the page JavaScript in-HTML code:

```
...
    function system_report(type) {

        sqlString = '', sqlFullString = '', rowcount = 0;

        $('#system tr').each(function() {
            if(rowcount > 0) {
                var editdata = this.cells[6].innerHTML.split("|");
                sqlString += editdata[0] + '|' + editdata[1] + '|' + editdata[7] + '|' + editdata[3] + '|' + editdata[4] + '|' + editdata[5] + '^';
                sqlFullString += this.cells[0].innerHTML + '|' + encodeURIComponent(this.cells[1].innerHTML) + '|' + this.cells[2].innerHTML + '|' + this.cells[3].innerHTML + '|' + this.cells[6].innerHTML + '^';
            }
            rowcount++;         
        });
        sqlString = sqlString.slice(0, -1)
...
```

Looks non trivial to reverse-engineer.

Although it's not a solution to your "sql" question above, I suggest that you try using [`splash` (an alternative to selenium in some cases).](https://splash.readthedocs.org/en/stable/)

You can launch it with docker (the easiest way):

```
$ sudo docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash
```

With the following script:

```
function main(splash)
  local url = splash.args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))

  -- this clicks the "Full SP" button
  assert(splash:runjs("$('#b-full-report').click()"))
  -- loading the report takes some time
  assert(splash:wait(5))
  return {
    html = splash:html()
  }
end
```

you can get the page HTML with the popup of the report.

You can integrate Splash with Scrapy using [`scrapyjs`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) (a.k.a `scrapy-splash`)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35851072/ with an example how to do so with a custom script.

Comment: Thanks a  lot. Thats what I thought. When I cannot figure it out them probably scrapyjs/selenium integration would work. Now i am working over it.
Actually I tried getting the sql query (the normal sql) from the table and tried it as well. I was just wondering it is so flavor of sql-javascript that I dont know of. Thanks for clearing my doubt.